# Roland BK-5 backing keyboard

Tags: keyboard, midi

I have a [Roland BK-5 keyboard](http://www.rolandus.com/products/details/1194). What is required to have the keyboard automatically change chords on backup rhythms when I play my guitar and change chords? Can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

If you were very experienced at working with MIDI and sequencer programming, and you had a MIDI interface on your guitar, it might be possible to work out a system to do this, but no, the Roland BK-5 does not have any features specific to interfacing with a guitar.

You ought to learn about guitar-to-MIDI interfaces, such as the [Fishman TriplePlay](http://www.fishman.com/tripleplay) and the [Roland GR-series of products](http://www.rolandus.com/products/category/477).